# set_include_path not include Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this statement:

```
set_include_path('/sites/intranet/includes/Zend' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

but when I try to use the Acl library it seems that is not able to find the file;

```
require_once 'Zend/Acl/Resource/Interface.php';
```

The path is really included in the path, I have printed it. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "Zend" is in your `require_once` instruction, you probably don't have to put it in your `include_path` too.

If your directories look like this :

```
/sites/intranet/includes/Zend/Acl/Resource/Interface.php
```

Your include_path should probably be :

```
set_include_path('/sites/intranet/includes' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

*(Without the "`Zend`" part)*

As a sidenote : why are you not using [the autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) ?

Comment: The answer is: (Without the "Zend" part)

Comment: I am using ZF just for Acl and I not interested in ZF at all. I have an intranet build with Qcodo framework but I hope to rewrite everyting in Rails or write new modules in Rails and un PHP, Qcodo and ZF as less as possible. Hopefully PHP 5.3 has namespaces as other more serious languages (but the syntax is rubish... they use the slash \ blahhh).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is because you already has `/Zend` in the include path? So either do this

```
set_include_path('/sites/intranet/includes' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

or

```
require_once 'Acl/Resource/Interface.php';
```

Due to the zend frameworks autoloader, the first one is recommended.